# Problema ao mudar foco de campo

Tags: c#, textbox

Estou com um problema ao mudar o foco de entrada entre os `TextBox` da minha aplicação.

O problema na verdade é o seguinte: O `tb_Estados` possui um `AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Append` e um `AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource`. Até aí, sem problemas.

As coisas começam a dar errado no princípio que, ao tentar mudar de textbox com ao pressionar o enter no evento `KeyPress` do `TextBox`, simplesmente "não ocorre nada".

```
private void tb_Estados_KeyPress_1(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.KeyChar == ((char)(Keys.Enter))))
    {
        tb_Cidades.Focus();
    }
}
```

O foco não muda para o `tb_Cidades`, mas sim permanece no `tb_Estados`.

O que notei que ocorre é que o texto informado no `tb_Estados` é todo selecionado ao pressionar a tecla Enter, ao invés de mudar o foco de entrada. Isto é, ele não muda o foco, apenas seleciona (caso haja algo inserido) o texto do `tb_Estado`. Caso não tenha nada inserido, ele simplesmente seleciona o " " e não troca para o `tb_Cidades`.

Tentei utilizar o `.Select()` ao invés de `.Focus()`, mas não adiantou.

Tentei também utilizar o `SendKeys` para enviar o comando de `{"Tab"}`, porém também não funcionou.

Agradeço a atenção e possíveis soluções de todos!

Comment: Tenta colocar um `e.Cancel = true` após o tb_Cidades.Focus();

Comment: Pode sempre experimentar `SelectNextControl(tb_Estados, true, true, true, true);`. Mas de qualquer forma parece-me que existe alguma propriedade no controlo `tb_Cidades` que esteja a impedir o foco.

Comment: Tenta colocar no KeyDown

if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
                e.Handled = true;
            }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aparentemente existe um bug que não foi corrigido pela microsoft sobre o [`AutoCompleteSource`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletesource?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Fiz um teste bem simples e realmente ao usar o `textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;` o `KeyPress` deixa de funcionar.

Se você comentar a linha o evento `KeyPress` volta a funcionar.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Append;
        textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyChar == ((char)(Keys.Enter))))
        {
            textBox2.Select();
        }
    }
}
```

[Achei isso relacionado ao problema](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d3d5347e-e34c-4706-b80c-1184fb1a3de4/combobox-autocomplete-focus-problem?forum=winforms), e aparentemente havia um link da microsoft onde ele foi reportado, mas o link já não existe mais. **Não sei se isso realmente se trata de um bug**, mas essa propriedade realmente desabilita o `KeyPress`. De qualquer forma, para o seu caso é melhor usar o `KeyDown`.

**Exemplo com KeyDown:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Append;
        textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            textBox2.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

E aqui você encontra um leitura interessante sobre a [diferença entra o KeyDown e KeyPress](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1367700/5522115).

Answer (score 1):

Agradeço imensamente a ajuda de todos. Conforme dito na resposta anterior, aparentemente é um bug da Microsoft que ainda não foi corrigido em relação ao `AutoCompleteSource`.

A solução que utilizei, mediante a todas as respostas foi:

No evento `KeyPress`:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.KeyChar == ((char)(Keys.Enter))))
    {
        textBox2.Select();
    }
}
```

e no evento `KeyDown`:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        textBox2.Focus();
    }
}
```

O detalhe foi que precisei utilizar em ambos eventos, não somente em um ou outro. De qualquer forma, grato a todos que despuseram-se a me ajudar!